# How to hide buttons from toolbar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, hide

I'm having a problem with toolbar buttons on an aspx page.
The method I use to render 2 more buttons only in Protocol page is the one below.
I render 2 buttons (Active,Archive) on toolbar only on Protocol page. But, I need to hide them when the book is archived. I tried to do it by checking if (Entity.IsArchived == 0 ) but it gives me the following error in interface :

**Error Details**

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The code for the method is :

```
protected override void OnPrepareButtons(SortedList<string, ImageButton> buttons)
{
        // Activate button
        ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
        img.ID = "btnActivate";
        img.AlternateText = "Activate";
        img.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnActivate_Click);
        img.CommandName = "Activate";
        img.ImageUrl = "~/Content/images/png/apply.png";
        img.Width = Unit.Pixel(25);
        img.Height = Unit.Pixel(25);
        img.ToolTip = "Activate";
        buttons.Add("Activate", img);

        // Archive button
        img = new ImageButton();
        img.ID = "btnArchive";
        img.AlternateText = "Archive";
        img.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnArchive_Click);
        img.CommandName = "Archive";
        img.ImageUrl = "~/Content/images/png/lock.png";
        img.Width = Unit.Pixel(25);
        img.Height = Unit.Pixel(25);
        img.ToolTip = "Archive";
        buttons.Add("Archive", img);

        base.OnPrepareButtons(buttons);

}
```

Any idea how to manage this situation please?

Comment: Does this error come from this code (which line) ? Or does it occur in __base.OnPrepareButtons__ ?

Comment: I added this lines of code after the last line : if (Entity.IsArchived == 1)
                {
                    img.Visible = false;
                }     but still generates the error :(

Comment: @jbl, if I leave the code as it is, without adding anything, it rebuilds ok and doesn't generate error, but it doesn't hide the buttons even though the book might be archived. If I add the lines of code, it generates the error I told you.

Comment: I guess that means __Entity__ property of your page/control has not yet been loaded when this code runs. When do you load your Entity ?  When does this code run ?

Comment: This code runs when page is rendered, so it shows the buttons on the page and user can Activate and Archive the book.

Comment: Entity is clearly null

Comment: @JeremyK, I have checked the db table which contains the protocol registry rows, and none of them has any null value.

Comment: Your code is not what is in the DB. You need to debug the code and see what the value is when you check IsArchived. Whatever you are doing to get Entity is either failing or not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error mentioned in your question because when you add the line to check if `Entity.IsArchived`, you are throwing a null exception. You need to debug where Entity is being set to see why it is null when you try to use it.

Once you solve why Entity is null, you will be able to successful check `IsArchived` and hide the image as necessary.

This is not a solution. In case you are not sure on debugging: If you added this instead:

```
if(Entity == null)
    MessageBox.Show("Entity is null!!");
```

You would see the message box :)